# Call getReserves() from goweb3

Tags: golang, polygon

I've been using https://github.com/umbracle/go-web3 as my go web3 library, and I am having trouble finding out how to call the "function getReserves(address factory, address tokenA, address tokenB) internal view returns (uint reserveA, uint reserveB)" of this contract on Polygon 0x1b02dA8Cb0d097eB8D57A175b88c7D8b47997506 (Sushiswap). I tried looking around for examples online but there is very little on Go Web3. Anyone able to have anything that can atleast get me in the right direction? Don't mind using another web3 library

what I am at so far is

```
Sushiloc := web3.HexToAddress("0x1b02dA8Cb0d097eB8D57A175b88c7D8b47997506")

Sushiabi, err := abi.NewABI("function getReserves(address factory, address tokenA, address tokenB) internal view returns (uint reserveA, uint reserveB)")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
msg := &web3.CallMsg{
    To:   &Sushiloc,
    Data: abi.Encode(, Sushiabi.Methods["getReserves"].Inputs),
}
client.Eth().Call(msg, web3.Latest)
```

But struggling with finding out how to complete that Encode() statement

Comment: `golang` apis are not web3

Comment: `Geth` exposes APIs through RPC, and then any software can connect to. web3 has nothing to do here

Comment: you can use `abigen` , https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/tree/master/cmd/abigen , just feed the ABI of Sushiswap to `abigen` and it will create the contract bindings in `golang` . Having the bindings you can call any method of the contract with just 1 line of code. It is very easy and there are lots of examples online

Comment: This `go-web3` project you posted is absolutely unnecessary. It is just one extra layer of abstraction. With `abigen` you won't need to encode / decode anything as Go is native language for Geth and you can use the types directly without encoding

Comment: @Nulik Ok, so I should just use the native Geth abigen package to call the contract? Would you mind showing how to send this transaction through RPC then? I am still having trouble understand where inputs go

Comment: have you googled? there are lots of examples. like this one: https://medium.com/hackernoon/a-step-by-step-guide-to-testing-and-deploying-ethereum-smart-contracts-in-go-9fc34b178d78 , just skip the deployment step

Comment: there is no "inputs" , just call solidity code from golang directly, with the parameters as they come

Comment: @Nulik meant params as input, my bad. That article helps! Guess my search engine just hates me :(, was only getting js examples

Comment: if you filter by `site:.medium.com`  in google you will get tons of high quality tutorials